# Detect vertical panning in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

How can I detect vertical `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on `UITableView`. I can detect horizontal but on vertical only the `UITableView` scrolls, and I can't get panning events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollview` so you can get hold of it's `panGestureRecognizer` and add your own action targets.

Answer (score 4):

What about using `UITableView`s delegate instead? `UITableViewDelegate` conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate` so you can use any of these methods for example:

```
– scrollViewDidScroll:
– scrollViewWillBeginDragging:
– scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:
– scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:
```

Comment: I have a tabbar on say half of the screen and keyboard is open i want to dismiss keyboard as soon as point of panning reaches tab bar frame. How can i detect the touch point related to UIScreen from panning so that i dismiss the keyboard?

Comment: scrolling delegates's result doesn't seems to be what i need

Comment: If you really need pan recognizer, Mike Pollard's answer seems fine. Maybe expand your question by desired behavior or what you are trying to achieve with the recognizer. It could give you better answers :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer i was able to get panning CGPoint from locationInView :)

Answer (score 2):

the UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, then you can access the panGestureRecognizer property

> panGestureRecognizer The underlying gesture recognizer for pan
>   gestures. (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly) UIPanGestureRecognizer
>   *panGestureRecognizer

See also the UItableViewDelegate methods

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```
 typedef enum : NSInteger
{
  kPanMoveDirectionNone,
  kPanMoveDirectionUp,
  kPanMoveDirectionDown,
  kPanMoveDirectionRight,
  kPanMoveDirectionLeft
} PanMoveDirection;

-(PanMoveDirection)determineDirectionIfNeeded:(CGPoint)translation
{
if (direction != kPanMoveDirectionNone)
    return direction;

// determine if horizontal swipe only if you meet some minimum velocity

if (fabs(translation.x) > 20)
{
    BOOL gestureHorizontal = NO;

    if (translation.y == 0.0)
        gestureHorizontal = YES;
    else
        gestureHorizontal = (fabs(translation.x / translation.y) > 5.0);

    if (gestureHorizontal)
    {
        if (translation.x > 0.0)
            return kPanMoveDirectionRight;
        else
            return kPanMoveDirectionLeft;
    }
}
// determine if vertical swipe only if you meet some minimum velocity

else if (fabs(translation.y) > 20)
{
    BOOL gestureVertical = NO;

    if (translation.x == 0.0)
        gestureVertical = YES;
    else
        gestureVertical = (fabs(translation.y / translation.x) > 5.0);

    if (gestureVertical)
    {
        if (translation.y > 0.0)
            return kPanMoveDirectionDown;
        else
            return kPanMoveDirectionUp;
    }
}
return direction;
}
```

call  direction = [self determineDirectionIfNeeded:translation]; in your pangesture targeted method